# Django 403 forbidden

Tags: python, django

Django 1.9.5
When I press the button on the console of my browser displayed an error "http://127.0.0.1:8000/encrypt   [HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden 4мс]"
What is the problem?

home.html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#encrypt").click(function () {
        var postData = {
            text: $("#input-box").val(),
            rotate: $("#rotate").val()
        };
        $.post('encrypt', postData);
        return false;
    });
});
  </script>

  <div class="container">
    <legend>Caesar cipher</legend>
    <div class="row">
      <form name="ciepher" method="POST" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <!--form code -->
         <button class="btn" name="encrypt" id="encrypt"><span class="icon-arrow-right"></span></button>
      </form>
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name="home"),
    url(r'^encrypt$', views.encrypt, name="encrypt")
]
```

views.py:

```
def home(request):
    return render_to_response("home.html", context_instance = RequestContext(request))

def encrypt(request):
    input_text = request.POST["text"]
    rotate = request.POST["rotate"]
    output_text = models.encode(input_text, rotate)
    frequency = models.get_frequency(input_text)
    return render_to_response("home.html", {'input_text': input_text, 'rotate': rotate, 'output_text': output_text, 'frequency': frequency}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Thank you

Comment: Please post your views, there must be a login/permission/test required failing somewhere.

Comment: Seems like a permission issue with your View. What does your View look like ?

Comment: @Jclarke Added views

Comment: This should help. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/#ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not sending the CSRF token. You have it in your form, but you're posting data via Ajax not via a normal form submission; you need to include the token in the Ajax post data.